# 'SelectListItem' has no key defined?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, scaffolding

After creating a telerik-mvc3 project I made some models.
I used scaffolding for creating the controller, the views.
when I Started the app I get this error:

```
    System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �SelectListItems� is based on type �SelectListItem� that has no keys defined.
```

on
 `return View(context.Medewerker.ToList());`

I don't have created the edm file, I do have on each table an ID with a primary key.
In the model I added [Key] as attribute to the id.

What else must I do?

Thanks

Comment: System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType - Are you using Entity Framework in this project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I do Entity FrameWork With the addon MvcScaffolding

Comment: Don't put your comments as answer - Add a comment to your question or edit your question.

Comment: @Jakub Konecki, I tried but the "Add Comment" button did not work even after starting an other browser. Again Sorry!!